# Fibonacci Boxes

Tags: c#, winforms, fibonacci

I know there's a lot of Fibonacci questions and answers on Stack overflow and the web in general, but this is a problem that's been vexing me for a while now, and i can't seem to crack it or find a solution.

Creating Fibonacci algorithms are easy enough, there's plenty of them, but i'm trying to create the boxes in a spiral formation graphically using C#. This is not for Uni or anything, it's just a problem that i've spent way too much time on that i now need to find a solution for, if you know what i mean?

Here's what i've got so far, now i did have a better configuration, but with countless hours of revising the code, this is what i have at the moment:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public const int FIBNUM = 6;
    public const int CENTRE = 10;
    public const int SIZE = 10;
    public const int OFFSET = 100;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        drawSpiral();
    }

    private int fib(int n)
    {
        switch (n)
        {
            case 0:
                return 0;
            case 1:
                return 1;
            default:
                return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
        }
    }

    private void drawSpiral()
    {
        if (pictureBox1.Image == null)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
        }

        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image))
        {
            Rectangle r = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);

            int fibnum = 0;
            int centre = 0;
            int size = 0;
            int cnt = 0;

            for (int n = 1; n <= FIBNUM; n++)
            {
                fibnum = fib(n);
                centre = fibnum * CENTRE;
                size = fibnum * SIZE;

                ++cnt;
                if (cnt == 1)
                {
                    if (n == 1)
                    {
                        r = new Rectangle(fibnum + OFFSET, fibnum + OFFSET, size, size);
                        g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, r);

                        r = new Rectangle((fibnum + size) + OFFSET, fibnum + OFFSET, size, size);
                        g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Purple, r);

                        n++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        r = new Rectangle((centre - size) + OFFSET, (centre - size) + OFFSET, size, size);        
                        g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, r);
                    }
                    continue;
                }
                if(cnt == 2)
                {
                    r = new Rectangle((fibnum) + OFFSET, (fibnum - size) + OFFSET, size, size);
                    g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, r);
                    continue;
                }
                if (cnt == 3)
                {
                    r = new Rectangle((fibnum - size) + OFFSET, (fibnum - size) + OFFSET, size, size);
                    g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Green, r);

                    continue;
                }
                if (cnt == 4)
                {
                    r = new Rectangle((fibnum - size / 2) + OFFSET, (fibnum - size) + OFFSET, size, size);
                    g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Gray, r);
                }
                cnt = 0;       
            }
        }
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    }
```

I've taken an image from wikipedia of what it is i'm trying to create graphically :

[image: fib boxes]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1.What is your actual problem? 2.Can you give us some code we can run (without the UI) if this in son a UI thing?

Comment: Are you having problems with the drawing part? linking the boxes together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your code is too complicated, because you try to do a lot at once. Consider the following code where the spiral is drawn around the origin, without scaling and translating:

```
// the current fibonacci numbers
int current = 1;
int previous = 0;

// the current bounding box
int left = 0;
int right = 1;
int top = 0;
int bottom = 0;

// the number of boxes you want to draw
const int N = 10;

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    switch (i % 4) {
        case 0: // attach to bottom of current rectangle
            drawRectangle(g, left, right, bottom, bottom + current);
            bottom += current;
            break;
        case 1: // attach to right of current rectangle
            drawRectangle(g, right, right + current, top, bottom);
            right += current;
            break;                
        case 2: // attach to top of current rectangle
            drawRectangle(g, left, right, top - current, top);
            top -= current;
            break; 
        case 3: // attach to left of current rectangle
            drawRectangle(g, left - current, left, top, bottom);
            left -= current;
            break; 
    }

    // update fibonacci number
    int temp = current;
    current += previous;
    previous = temp;
}
```

You can then deal with the actual drawing part in the separate method `drawRectangle` (I left out all details about the actual graphics objects, but you can probably do that yourself).

```
const int SCALE = 5;
const int OFFSET = 150;

private void drawRectangle(Graphics g, int left, int right, int top, int bottom)
{
    g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, new Rectangle(SCALE * left + OFFSET, 
                                            SCALE * top + OFFSET, 
                                            SCALE * (right - left),
                                            SCALE * (bottom - top)));
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, with a few tweaks & changes i think i've now got exactly what i was after ;)

Comment: @DraconianTimes You're right. I initialized `right` to `1` now and the output is correct, besides, I added some scaling to create a nicer picture (see the printscreen)

Comment: Perfect! i rejigged it a little, but this is exactly what i was trying to achieve. Not sure i'll try to put the golden spiral in the boxes though, maybe too tough lol

Answer (score 1):

Here you go :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public const int FIBNUM = 8;
    public const int CENTERX = 300;
    public const int CENTERY = 300;
    public const int ZOOM = 10;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        drawSpiral();
    }

    private int fib(int n, int p = 0, int q = 1)
    {
        switch (n)
        {
            case 0: return 0;
            case 1: return q;
            default: return fib(n - 1, q, p + q);
        }
    }

    private void drawSpiral()
    {
        if (pictureBox1.Image == null)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
        }

        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image))
        {
            Rectangle r = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);

            int x = CENTERX;
            int y = CENTERY;

            for (int n = 1; n <= FIBNUM; n++)
            {
                int fibnum = fib(n)*ZOOM;

                r = new Rectangle(x, y, fibnum, fibnum);
                g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, r);

                switch (n % 4)
                {
                    case 0:
                        {
                            y += fibnum;
                            break;
                        }
                    case 1:
                        {
                            x += fibnum;
                            y -= fib(n - 1) * ZOOM;
                            break;
                        }
                    case 2:
                        {
                            x -= fib(n - 1)*ZOOM;
                            y -= fib(n + 1)*ZOOM;
                            break;
                        }
                    case 3:
                        {
                            x -= fib(n + 1) * ZOOM;
                            break;
                        }
                }
            }
            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that i have changed your fibonacci function with a better performing one ; in particular, mine calculates the next fibonacci number in linear time.
With some MatheMagic ( sorry for the joke :) ) you can make it even smarter, and obtain

```
    private int move(int n, int a, int currentFib)
    {
        switch (a)
        {
            case 1: return currentFib;
            case 2: return -fib(n - 1) * ZOOM;
            case 3: return -fib(n + 1) * ZOOM;
            default: return 0;
        }
    }

    private void drawSpiral()
    {
        if (pictureBox1.Image == null)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
        }

        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image))
        {
            Rectangle r = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);

            int x = CENTERX;
            int y = CENTERY;

            for (int n = 1; n <= FIBNUM; n++)
            {
                int fibnum = fib(n)*ZOOM;

                r = new Rectangle(x, y, fibnum, fibnum);
                g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, r);

                x += move(n, n % 4, fibnum);
                y += move(n, (n + 1) % 4, fibnum);
            }
            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private int fib(int n)
{
    switch (n)
    {
        case 0:
            return 0;
        case 1:
            return 1;
        default:
            return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
    }
}
```

That is enough slow,maybe it doesn't matter in this task but isn't it better to use an array `fib[1..n]` (`fib[0]=0` `fib[1]=1` `for(i = 2;i<=n;i++)fib[i]=fib[i-1]+fib[i-2]`) that will work in `O(n)` not in `O(n*(1.7^n))`